Expanded widget goes on a new line Flutter app
I have a Flutter app and a custom input field. In it, both text and tags can be added. I have two problems:

Initially, the textfield is wrapped in Expanded widget. By setting  maxLines and minLines, I am able to spit the text on two lines if it exceeds the parent width. However, when I add a tag, the whole text goes on the first line which is not expected. The tag should be placed next to the text on the second line.
The last textfield that is added is wrapped in expanded, however, this brings the textfield on a new line. It should fill in the remaining width of the current row with text and tags and if the parent width is exceeded, the text should go on a new line.

Here is a full code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tagfield_demo/tag_textfield.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final GlobalKey<TagTextFieldState> _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100)).then((val) {
      setState(() {
        print(val);
      });
    });
    return TextFieldTapRegion(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: TagTextField(
                  key: _key,
                  initialText: "",
                  tagTextBuilder: (BuildContext context, String tag) {
                    switch (tag) {
                      case '[Amount]':
                        return 'Amount';
                      case '[Location]':
                        return 'Location';
                    }

                    return tag;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text("Add Location tag"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_key.currentState != null) {
                        _key.currentState!.addTag('[Location]');
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text("Add Amount tag"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_key.currentState != null) {
                        _key.currentState!.addTag('[Amount]');
                      }
                    },
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

the custom tag input field:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class TagTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  final String initialText;
  final String Function(BuildContext context, String tag)? tagTextBuilder;
  final String? hint;

  const TagTextField({
    super.key,
    this.initialText = '',
    this.tagTextBuilder,
    this.hint,
  });

  @override
  State<TagTextField> createState() => TagTextFieldState();
}

class TagTextFieldState extends State<TagTextField> {
  late String _text;
  late List<Widget> _children;
  late List<TextEditingController?> _textControllers;
  late List<GlobalKey<_TagState>?> _tagKeys;
  late List<FocusNode?> _focusNodes;
  final FocusNode _mainFocusNode = FocusNode(); // Add this focus node

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _text = widget.initialText;

    _children = [];
    _textControllers = [];
    _focusNodes = [];
    _tagKeys = [];

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((Duration duration) {
      _refreshChildren();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (var node in _focusNodes) {
      if (node != null) {
        node.dispose();
      }
    }

    for (var controller in _textControllers) {
      if (controller != null) {
        controller.dispose();
      }
    }

    for (var tag in _tagKeys) {
      if (tag != null && tag.currentState != null) {
        tag.currentState!.dispose();
      }
    }

    _mainFocusNode.dispose(); // Dispose the main focus node

    super.dispose();
  }

  addTag(String tag) {
    //Adds tag on cursor position
    int idx = 0;
    int position = 0;
    for (var node in _focusNodes) {
      if (node != null) {
        var controller = _textControllers[idx];

        if (node.hasFocus) {
          var cursorPos = controller!.selection.base.offset;
          position += cursorPos;
          break;
        } else {
          position += controller!.text.length;
        }
      } else {
        var tag = _tagKeys[idx];
        if (tag != null && tag.currentState != null) {
          position += tag.currentState!.getTag().length;
        }
      }

      idx++;
    }

    //Add tag in text
    _text = _text.replaceRange(position, position, tag);

    for (var node in _focusNodes) {
      if (node != null) {
        node.unfocus();
      }
    }

    setState(() {
      _refreshChildren();
    });
  }

  getText() {
    int idx = 0;

    _text = '';

    for (var controller in _textControllers) {
      if (controller != null) {
        _text += controller.text;
      } else {
        var tag = _tagKeys[idx];
        if (tag != null && tag.currentState != null) {
          _text += tag.currentState!.getTag();
        }
      }

      idx++;
    }

    return _text;
  }

  void _onFocusChange(FocusNode focusNode) {
    if (focusNode.hasFocus) {
      for (var node in _focusNodes) {
        if (node != null && node != focusNode) {
          node.unfocus();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  bool _onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event, FocusNode focusNode) {
    if (event is KeyDownEvent &&
        event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace) {
      final idx = _focusNodes.indexOf(focusNode);
      if (idx > 0 && _textControllers[idx]!.selection.base.offset == 0) {
        final prevIdx = idx - 1;
        if (_textControllers[prevIdx] == null && _tagKeys[prevIdx] != null) {
          final tag = _tagKeys[prevIdx]!.currentState!.getTag();
          _text = _text.replaceRange(
              _tagKeys[prevIdx]!.currentState!.widget.startPos,
              _tagKeys[prevIdx]!.currentState!.widget.startPos + tag.length,
              '');
          for (var node in _focusNodes) {
            if (node != null) {
              node.unfocus();
            }
          }

          setState(() {
            _refreshChildren();
          });
        }
      }
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  _createTextField({String? text, bool showHint = false, bool isLast = false}) {
    _textControllers.add(TextEditingController(text: text));

    _textControllers.last!.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        getText();
      });
    });

    _focusNodes.add(FocusNode());
    _focusNodes.last!.addListener(() {
      _onFocusChange(_focusNodes.last!);
    });

    // Add key event listener
    _focusNodes.last!.addListener(() {
      if (_focusNodes.last!.hasFocus) {
        HardwareKeyboard.instance.addHandler((event) {
          return _onKeyEvent(event, _focusNodes.last!);
        });
      } else {
        HardwareKeyboard.instance.removeHandler((event) {
          return _onKeyEvent(event, _focusNodes.last!);
        });
      }
    });

    //Add empty elements, so indexes match
    _tagKeys.add(null);

    Widget textField = TextField(
      focusNode: _focusNodes.last,
      controller: _textControllers.last,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: showHint ? widget.hint : null,
        border: InputBorder.none,
      ),
    );

    if (showHint || isLast) {
      textField = Expanded(
        child: TextField(
          focusNode: _focusNodes.last,
          controller: _textControllers.last,
          minLines: 1,
          maxLines: null,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: showHint ? widget.hint : null,
            border: InputBorder.none,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      textField = IntrinsicWidth(child: textField);
    }

    _children.add(
      Baseline(
        baseline: 20.0,
        baselineType: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        child: textField,
      ),
    );
  }

  _createTag(String tag, int startPos) {
    if (_children.isEmpty) {
      _createTextField();
    }

    String label = tag;
    if (widget.tagTextBuilder != null) {
      label = widget.tagTextBuilder!(context, tag);
    }

    //Add empty elements, so indexes match
    _textControllers.add(null);
    _focusNodes.add(null);
    _tagKeys.add(GlobalKey<_TagState>());

    _children.add(
      Baseline(
        baseline: 20.0,
        baselineType: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
        child: Tag(
          key: _tagKeys.last,
          label: label,
          tag: tag,
          startPos: startPos,
          onDelete: () {
            _text = _text.replaceRange(startPos, startPos + tag.length, '');
            for (var node in _focusNodes) {
              if (node != null) {
                node.unfocus();
              }
            }

            setState(() {
              _refreshChildren();
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _refreshChildren() {
    _children.clear();
    _textControllers.clear();
    _focusNodes.clear();
    _tagKeys.clear();

    final regex = RegExp(r'(\[(.*?)\])');
    final matches = regex.allMatches(_text);
    var currentIndex = 0;

    if (_text.isEmpty) {
      //Only one starting text field
      _createTextField(showHint: true);
      return;
    }

    for (final match in matches) {
      final beforeText = _text.substring(currentIndex, match.start);
      if (beforeText.isNotEmpty) {
        _createTextField(text: beforeText);
      } else {
        _createTextField();
      }

      final tag = match.group(1);

      _createTag(tag!, match.start);

      currentIndex = match.end;
    }

    final afterText = _text.substring(currentIndex);
    if (afterText.isNotEmpty) {
      _createTextField(text: afterText, isLast: true);
    } else {
      _createTextField(isLast: true);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardListener(
      focusNode: _mainFocusNode, // Set the main focus node
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
        child: Wrap(
          children: _children,
        ),
      ),
      onKeyEvent: (event) {
        _onKeyEvent(event, _mainFocusNode);
      },
    );
  }
}

class Tag extends StatefulWidget {
  final String tag;
  final String label;
  final int startPos;
  final VoidCallback onDelete;

  const Tag(
      {super.key,
      required this.tag,
      required this.label,
      required this.startPos,
      required this.onDelete});

  @override
  State<Tag> createState() => _TagState();
}

class _TagState extends State<Tag> {
  String getTag() {
    return widget.tag;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xFF2A2C42),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(90),
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 10),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(
            widget.label.toUpperCase(),
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 5),
          SizedBox(
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: widget.onDelete,
              backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF2A2C42),
              mini: true,
              child: const Icon(Icons.close),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


I'm not sure I understand exactly the type of behaviour you're aiming for. I added a few parameters like keyboardType:TextInputType.multiline,textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline and style: const TextStyle(overflow: TextOverflow.clip,). Does this solve the issue? Demo here

I edited the demo above to also include maxLines: null in the Widget textField = TextField() variable inside _createTextField

@Texv If the field is empty and you add a tag, then the last textfield is added on a new line. However, it should go next to the tag and expand till the end of the row. Regarding the other problem, if the textfield is empty and you start typing, if the text is more than a line long, if you add a tag after that, the text will go on the first line and some part won't be visible. The idea is that the tag is not placed next to the text.

I understand now. It seems that when adding a new tag, it forces the cursor to a new line and you also can't move the cursor to the end of the tag like you could to a regular text for continued typing

@Texv yeah, exactly and unfortunately I am not able to fix this behavior for a few days already

You need to remove this if/else statement in _createTextField:
if (showHint || isLast)

and always having the textField wrapped with an IntrinsicWidth.
Widget textField = IntrinsicWidth(
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: _focusNodes.last,
            controller: _textControllers.last,
            maxLines: null,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: showHint ? widget.hint : null,
              border: InputBorder.none,
              //suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.pending),
            ),
          ),
        );

This is probably because a TextField widget will always naturally expand to the maximum available width space hence starting at a new line where there is more width (just like how a long text goes to the next line.
The bordered container will then shrink, in which you can fix by adding this parameter to keep it expanded:
width: double.infinity

The only problem now is you need to press on the very left corner of the textfield to get the cursor/focus up. So to work around that I added a GestureDetector to request focus on the last focusNode when tapping anywhere within the container.
        child: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodes.last);
            });
          },
          child: Wrap...

And finally, to maintain the mouse cursor I-beam shape when overing over the container, I used a MouseRegion Widget which will detect when a mouse pointer enters, exits or hovers over its child widget.
MouseRegion(
            cursor: SystemMouseCursors.text,
            child: GestureDetector...

Full code changes:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardListener(
      focusNode: _mainFocusNode, // Set the main focus node
      child: MouseRegion(
        cursor: SystemMouseCursors.text,
        child: GestureDetector(
          behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNodes.last);
            });
          },
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent)),
            child: Wrap(
              children: _children,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onKeyEvent: (event) {
        _onKeyEvent(event, _mainFocusNode);
      },
    );
  }
}

See full working code demo on DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=05d8f3eed9e6f541514477e52a2e3ccd
